# CSS-only nav menu - need root element to stay darkened when open

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a CSS-only navigation menu I'm trying to finish up. It is almost complete except for one thing: When a user hovers over an element with a submenu then navigates down to the submenu the root element goes back to white. I would like the root navigation element to stay darkened when the submenu is open.  Below is a CodePen with my implementation so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJjyb

Can anyone help me finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this Selector (Line 51):

```
#navmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#navmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover
```

to this:

```
#navmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#navmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover > a
```

This results in the :hover Action still being active when the User is in the submenu as that is not a Children of the `<a>`- but the `<li>`-Tag

Comment: Holy cow, thank you so much. That did it. I will mark this as an answer when it will let me (in 7 minutes).